# How to move excel sheets saved in a folder to a new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

"C:\Users\New folder\"  in this path I do have 10 workbooks and each has budget tab...I want to move this tab to "code2.xlsm

My code is this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub move_filesinto_masterWB()


Dim Myfile As String
Myfile = Dir("C:\Users\New folder\")
Dim Masterwb As Workbook
Set Masterwb = Workbooks("code2.xlsm")


Do While Len(Myfile) > 0

Workbooks.Open (Myfile)

Sheets("budget").Select
Sheets("budget").Copy After:=Workbooks("Code2.xlsm").Sheets(sheets.count)

Myfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Need to know what is wrong with your code, what the desired output is, etc.

Comment: I am trying this code but it's not working

Comment: it gives "run time error 1004" xyz.xls could not found, but I do have approx. 10 workbooks there in the folder

Comment: Where does `xyz.xls` come from?

Comment: C:\Users\New folder\    in this path I do have 10 workbooks and each has budget tab...I want to move this tab to "code2.xlsm"

Comment: The title of your post is not for asking questions. Please give an appropriate title to your post and then ask the question in the body of the post. Also please be clear so that we can help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
Workbooks.Open (Myfile)
```

`Myfile` only contains the name of the file and not the full path. Try this

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\New folder\" & Myfile)
```

Comment: Now that I have helped you, could you help me with what I requested in the comment below your post ;)